# regex - How to create date format regex without repeating previous group

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex for matching date formats entered by a user. The user will enter date formats as a string ("*dd/MMM/yyyy*") and not actual values.

For example:

- dd/MMM/yyyy = ✅
- MMM/dd/yyyy = ✅
- dd/dd/yyyy = ❌ (previously captured groups cannot be repeated)
- MMM/MMM/yyyy = ❌ (same reason as above)

I'm having issues with working negative lookahead. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: You wish to reject `"04112020"`? If so, is it because the month must always be expressed as a three-letter abbreviation (e.g., `"Jan"` or `"JAN"`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't mean the actual date value, just the format itself. A user can enter "dd/MMM/yyyy" or "MMM/dd/yyyy" and it will pass but if they "MMM/MMM/yyyy" or "dd/dd/yyyy" it fails because they've already provided a format for month and day respectively.

Comment: I see. Are `"ddmmyyyy"` and `"mmddyyyy"` both valid?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes both valid.

Comment: You need to edit your question to incorporate the information in your first comment. You already have two votes to close, probably because of confusion over that point. Questions need to be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the advise. I updated my question as soon as I read your 1st comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use the regular expression

```
\b(?:dd\/(?:mm|MMM)\/yyyy|(?:mm|MMM)\/dd\/yyyy|yyyy\/(?:mm|MMM)\/dd)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P04qVd/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b                      # match a word break
(?:                     # begin a non-capture group
  dd\/(?:mm|MMM)\/yyyy  # match 'dd/' followed by 'mm' or 'MMM'
                        # followed by '/yyyy'
  |                     # or
  (?:mm|MMM)\/dd\/yyyy  # match 'mm' or 'MMM' followed by '/dd'
                        # followed by '/yyyy'
  |                     # or
  yyyy\/(?:mm|MMM)\/dd  # match 'yyyy/' followed by 'mm' or 'MMM'
                        # followed by 'dd'
)
\b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it works perfectly. Here is my full regex `^(?:d{1,2}([./-])(?:M{2,4})\1(y{2}|y{4})|(?:M{2,4})([./-])d{1,2}\3(y{2}|y{4})|(y{2}|y{4})([./-])(?:M{2,4})\6d{1,2})\s[Hh]{2}:[m]{2}:[s]{2}?$`